# Why can't I answer a question that requires a reputation level less than mine?

Tags: support, bug

I not able to post an answer to [Create a Bootable Windows USB from a OS X to work on a PC](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/123570/create-a-bootable-windows-usb-from-a-os-x-to-work-on-a-pc)? It states "posting an answer now requires 10 reputation," but I have a reputation of 101.

Comment: http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/cant-answer-a-protected-question-despite-having-sufficient-reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rep you earned linking your SE account doesn't count, unfortunately. You need to earn 10 rep points *on Ask Different organically* to be able to answer that question. You can get those points through voting, answering non-protected questions, asking questions, editing posts, etc.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I didn't realize (or remember) that those points were from linking accounts. I also don't think the difference was made clear in the notice or the "reputation" link. Might be an opportunity to improve the site.

Comment: I agree. We'll look into editing the site text to make it clearer.